# Flutter text display issue

Tags: text, flutter

Am writing a very basic app that just displays numbers on the screen and you can increase and decrease the value of this number with some buttons.

Works fine, except for some reason the text display often goes nuts.   I'll show you what I mean:

[image: display issue]

The above text is trying to display a value of 20, but it is struggling for some reason, as you can see.

This only appears to be happening with double-digit or higher values.  My code:

```
class _SinglePlayerModeParentState extends State<SinglePlayerMode> {

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,]);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget numberDisplay = GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print("GestureDetector");
    _incrementBy1();
  },
  child: Center(child: Text(_numberValue.toString(),
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 200.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This code was already displaying these text issues before I rearranged the code to include the following as well:

```
Widget buttonRow() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
       children: <Widget>[
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 20.0),
           child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              onPressed: _numberValueMinus5,
              child: Text('-5'),
            ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 40.0),
           child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              onPressed: _numberValueMinus1,
              child: Text('-1'),
            ),
         ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 20.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              onPressed: _numberValuePlus1,
              child: Text('+1'),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 40.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              onPressed: _numberValuePlus5,
              child: Text('+5'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Bean Counter',
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90.0, bottom: 40.0),
          child: numberDisplay,
        ),
        buttonRow(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Not sure what I can do differently here, it's just text!

Any thoughts?

Edit: Testing the FittedBox solution.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget numberDisplay = GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("GestureDetector");
      _incrementBy1();
    },
    child: Center(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text(_numberValue.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 200.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

}
```

Results:   this is trying to display the number 30:

[image: Text issue 2]

As you can see, it still isn't displaying properly.  I also tried BoxFit.contain, same issue. Information obtained from this reference:  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

Any other ideas guys?  Or did I implement FittedBox incorrectly?

Edit:   Tried with AutoSizeText, as recommended below.  Code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget scoreText = GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print("GestureDetector");
    _incrementBy1();
  },
  child: Center(
    child: AutoSizeText(_numberValue.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 200.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Results:

[image: Text issue 3]

Argh!  Displaying text on a clear screen.   Level:  difficult.

Comment: try to wrap your text with a FittedBox

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I had no luck with this solution, please see updates with my results in the main question.   Did I do this wrong?  Thanks again, Raouf.

Comment: issue is with how you are rendering whole screen. code that you have shared works fine otherwise.

Comment: needs more details like whats the parent of this widget

Comment: Have updated the code to include the whole section, but I have been making many changes to this today, it was previously just a number on the screen, and this text issue was happening from the start.  The only layout related code that has been there the whole time really is the systemchrome section.

Comment: Try to use the `AutoSizeText` package link here: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auto_size_text

Comment: Tried this, code and result added above.   Not sure why this is so hard!  Wondering if it is some flutter display bug?   But it's just text.....

Comment: Just as an update to this, in testing the text only breaks down over a certain size point, which seems to me like it is going outside of some invisible container.  But I tested with background colouring all the components and I found that initially, the text was housed in a narrow column.   I expanded this container to occupy the entire top half of the screen and the text still breaks over a certain size.   The text I am allowed to use without it breaking is far too small however.  This must be a bug, right?

Comment: Update: This did not fix it at all.  I have tried dozens of different methods of containing the text but it breaks every single time it exceeds a font size of 130.   No matter the container or any way of sizing the container.   The only thing that seems to not make the font crash is to use BoxFit.fitWidth... which makes the font size like 4000 and half hangs off the screen, but interestingly does not glitch graphically at all.   This problem is still a problem and it still really, really sucks.